# Backbone - get method not returning the out put

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

i am new to Backbone.js, i have a data set, assigned to view, but i can't get the data, while i console that any one tell me what is wrong with my code?

code:

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    data:[
        {text:'Google',href:"http://www.google.com"},
        {text:'Yahoo',href:"http://www.yahoo.com"},
        {text:'Bing',href:"http://www.bing.com"}
    ]
});

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function(){
       this.render();
    },
    render:function(){
         var data = this.model.get('data');
        console.log(data);    
    }
});

var myView = new View({model:model});
```

the error i am getting is here:

```
TypeError: this.model.get is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

var data = this.model.get('data');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually instantiate the model; using `extend` just creates an extension of the `Backbone.Model` prototype.  [The following creates a new *instance* of `Backbone.Model`](http://jsfiddle.net/rKeDq/), and initializes it with the data:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({
    data:[
        {text:'Google',href:"http://www.google.com"},
        {text:'Yahoo',href:"http://www.yahoo.com"},
        {text:'Bing',href:"http://www.bing.com"}
    ]
});
var myView = new View({ model: model });
```

---

If you want to put the data in the *type* of the model itself, then you could use the `defaults` property:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        data:[
            {text:'Google',href:"http://www.google.com"},
            {text:'Yahoo',href:"http://www.yahoo.com"},
            {text:'Bing',href:"http://www.bing.com"}
        ]
    }
});
var model = new Model();
var myView = new View({ model: model });
```

Comment: agree. works fine. but is there any situation to use this "Backbone.Model.extend({})" - ? if so when?

Comment: @3gwebtrain yes, for example, when it's associated with a specific URL, or when you want to define defaults or validation, or other specific behaviors.  It's well worth reading through the docs on the Backbone site for more info on this:  http://backbonejs.org/#Model

Comment: You'd probably want to use a `defaults` *function* for data like that, shallow copying and all that.